# Speech recognition grammar for free-form dictation

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is there any way to get all English grammar in a file or as DB, so that i can load those words to `SpeechRecognition` engine. Right now i'm adding it as follows and the choices are what ever i'm hard coding like "Start", "Stop"..

```
Choices texts = new Choices();
...
Grammar wordsList = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(texts));
```

I want to create an application, which creates words or sentences what ever the user is saying thru microphone

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is a practical approach.  Didn't Dragon Speech solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You want a [DictationGrammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar.aspx), not a Grammar (which is for command & control).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DictationGrammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar.aspx) class. I guess you are using C#. Following code will give you idea to how to use DictationGrammar object and load it to recognition engine.

```
using (
      SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer =
      new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")))
{
   DictationGrammar dg = new DictationGrammar();

   recognizer.LoadGrammar(dg);

   recognizer.RecognizeAsync();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grammars are used for directed dialog which restricts the expected phrases that the speech recognition engine expects to hear. What you are describing is natural language or dictation type of speech recognition.  These types of systems do not use grammars and are very different types of speech recognition engines.  [Dragon NaturallySpeaking](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-pc/premium-version/index.htm) is an example of this type of platform.